# create rest api url to connect with mysql database

Tags: mysql, rest, api

I want to learn how to create a rest api url so that I could get and post information into my mysql database using that url.

Googled alot and read various article and didnt find anything precise to learn on this. All are start with about apis and ends with already created rest urls.

Can anyone help on this ?

How to create my own url and authorization key etc ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:
 https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api

CRUD stands for:
**C**reate
**R**ead
**U**pdate
**D**elete

This api is written in PHP and gives you a simple and comfortable opportunity to
access your database (MySQL, SQLite 3, PostgreSQL 9 orMS SQL Server 2012). Its well documented and its gonna be easy to get started.

If you need something more custom and not only raw data you should write your own api with help of an framework for example the [SlimFramework](http://www.slimframework.com/), where you can specify the methods for requests.

Cause for rest apis there are more methods than GET and POST.

Good Luck ;)

Comment: I couldn't agree more ;-)

Comment: Note that you can now use [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) as a library in the [SlimFramework](http://www.slimframework.com/) for the best of both worlds.