# API Base URL for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, api, url, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to integrate Google Cloud SQL for Mysql into another application.  The other application wants the "api base url". Does anyone know how to get the "api base url" of Google Cloud SQL for Mysql?

Comment: as per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#pools) here is the URL mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>, is that works for you?

Comment: for <db_user> and <db_pass> my database username and password would be a part of the URL?

Comment: please look at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39517209/11866104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Google Cloud SQL and you are trying to connect your external application this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview) is the best for your case. In that document discuss the summary of [connection options](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview#connection_options), [authorization options](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview#authentication_options) and [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview#languages) also the [tools for connecting](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview#tools_for_connecting) that will help you to connect in Cloud SQL Mysql instance.

If you are referring to the [reference of REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest) of Cloud SQL and its [service-endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest#service-endpoint)(`https://www.googleapis.com`), these are some examples:

| Method | Format | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| delete | DELETE /sql/v1beta4/projects/{project}/instances/{instance}/databases/{database} | Deletes a database from a Cloud SQL instance. |
| get | GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/{project}/instances/{instance}/databases/{database} | Retrieves a resource containing information about a database inside a Cloud SQL instance. |
| insert | POST /sql/v1beta4/projects/{project}/instances/{instance}/databases | Inserts a resource containing information about a database inside a Cloud SQL instance. |
| update | PUT /sql/v1beta4/projects/{project}/instances/{instance}/databases/{database} | Updates a resource containing information about a database inside a Cloud SQL instance. |

> **NOTE:** You need to [enable the Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api#enabling_the_api) before using it.